# Unable to combine input and additional data to formdata in Next.js using server actions

Tags: next.js

I'm working with Next.js and building a web application for FIFA ranking in my city. I have faced the problem, I don't know how to include additional data into FormData that is not a part of simple input. To be more precise, I'm using uploadthing, where I upload image and then receive link of this image on the server.

```
'use client'
import { Input } from "@/components/ui/input"
import { CldUploadButton } from 'next-cloudinary';
import addUser from "@/components/actions/addUser";
import "@uploadthing/react/styles.css";
import { UploadButton } from "@/utils/uploadthing";

export default function Page(){
    return(
        <form className="flex flex-col items-center" action={addUser}>
            <div className='flex flex-col justify-center align-middle gap-4'>
                    <Input className="w-[200px]" type="text"  name="name" placeholder="name" />
                    <Input className="w-[200px]" type="text" name="login" placeholder="login" required />
                    <Input className="w-[200px]" type="text" name="elo" defaultValue={1000} />
            </div>
            <UploadButton
                endpoint="imageUploader"
                onClientUploadComplete={(res) => {
                // Do something with the response
                return res!==undefined ? res[0].fileUrl : null;
                }}
                onUploadError={(error: Error) => {
                // Do something with the error.
                alert(`ERROR! ${error.message}`);
                }}
                />
            <button className="" type="submit">Submit </button>
        </form>
    )
}
```

What should I do, so I can include urllink into formdata?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same question, which I managed to solve by using [`uploadFiles`](https://docs.uploadthing.com/api-reference/server#uploadfiles) from the UploadThing API rather than the provided `UploadButton`. That way, you're using the normal `<input type="file" />` in your form and the chosen file(s) get added to the `formData` in your server action.
Obviously, this means you have to implement and style your own button in the form if you want it to do the same thing as the `UploadButton`.